# Run application as root by default on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

I'm using Launch as Root at this point to launch apps as root but I'd like to make it so that an app runs as root by default. Is it possible to modify the shortcut to the app for the dock icon so it runs as root?

**UPDATE:**

This is in regards to PyCharm 2.7, it doesn't launch unless it's running as root. I get an error stating that Permission is denied to access a folder otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

Do not run applications as root.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I just added an Update to help clarify my request. If there isn't a way, there isn't a way I guess. Thanks.

Comment: That is either a bug in the application, or an issue with other permissions on your system. It should not be necessary under any circumstances.

Comment: PyCharm shouldn't need it; I've installed multiple versions of it across multiple instances of OSX. Try removing it with a tool like AppCleaner (http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), doing a "Repair Permissions" on your hard drive, and then reinstalling PyCharm.